# Blender crashes when exporting large amounts of high poly models and 4K textures as GLTF. What is causing Blender to crash?

Tags: python, export, gpu, performance, file-format

**Setup:**

So I have a script running that exports thousands of models from Blender to a .gltf file(s). These models are big, about 200MB each, and the goal is to export about 6,000 of them. What my script does is select the objects in the Blender file scene, then export them with this function:

```
for obj in bpy.data.collections[some_collection].all_objects:
    obj.select_set(True)

bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf(
   filepath=f"{Save_Path_To_Model_File}.gltf",
   check_existing=True,
   export_format='GLTF_SEPARATE',
   use_selection=True)
```

Materials are also selected in a similar way and are unique for each export:

```
for obj in bpy.data.collections[some_collection].all_objects:
    selected_object = bpy.data.objects.get(obj.name)
    selected_object.active_material = bpy.data.materials[some_material]
```

**The issue:**

After this code runs for about 17 loops, exporting 17 models, Blender crashes and an error message appears saying that Blender has run out of VRAM: `RuntimeError: Error: System is out of GPU and shared host memory`

Most of the time Blender just shuts down and doesn't display this message in the System Console when it reboots so I haven't been able to get the full message. But I'll edit it in this post if I manage to get it.

**Traceback from the .crash.txt file when exporting .gltf files:**

```
RuntimeError: Error: Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\__init__.py", line 628, in execute
    return gltf2_blender_export.save(context, export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_export.py", line 35, in save
    json, buffer = __export(export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_export.py", line 52, in __export
    __gather_gltf(exporter, export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_export.py", line 66, in __gather_gltf
    active_scene_idx, scenes, animations = gltf2_blender_gather.gather_gltf2(export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather.py", line 30, in gather_gltf2
    scenes.append(__gather_scene(blender_scene, export_settings))
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 38, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather.py", line 67, in __gather_scene
    node = gltf2_blender_gather_nodes.gather_node(
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_nodes.py", line 31, in gather_node
    children=__gather_children(vnode, blender_object, export_settings),
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_nodes.py", line 109, in __gather_children
    child_node = gather_node(vtree.nodes[child], export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_nodes.py", line 31, in gather_node
    children=__gather_children(vnode, blender_object, export_settings),
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_nodes.py", line 73, in __gather_children
    node = gather_node(c, export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_nodes.py", line 31, in gather_node
    children=__gather_children(vnode, blender_object, export_settings),
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_nodes.py", line 73, in __gather_children
    node = gather_node(c, export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_nodes.py", line 35, in gather_node
    mesh=__gather_mesh(vnode, blender_object, export_settings),
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_nodes.py", line 246, in __gather_mesh
    result = gltf2_blender_gather_mesh.gather_mesh(blender_mesh,
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 38, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_mesh.py", line 61, in gather_mesh
    primitives=__gather_primitives(blender_mesh, uuid_for_skined_data, vertex_groups, modifiers, materials, export_settings),
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_mesh.py", line 147, in __gather_primitives
    return gltf2_blender_gather_primitives.gather_primitives(blender_mesh,
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 38, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_primitives.py", line 81, in gather_primitives
    material = gltf2_blender_gather_materials.gather_material(
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 38, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_materials.py", line 53, in gather_material
    pbr_metallic_roughness, uvmap_actives_pbr_metallic_roughness = __gather_pbr_metallic_roughness(blender_material, orm_texture, export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_materials.py", line 334, in __gather_pbr_metallic_roughness
    return gltf2_blender_gather_materials_pbr_metallic_roughness.gather_material_pbr_metallic_roughness(
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 38, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_materials_pbr_metallic_roughness.py", line 19, in gather_material_pbr_metallic_roughness
    metallic_roughness_texture, use_active_uvmap_metallic_roughness_texture = __gather_metallic_roughness_texture(blender_material, orm_texture, export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_materials_pbr_metallic_roughness.py", line 140, in __gather_metallic_roughness_texture
    return gltf2_blender_gather_texture_info.gather_texture_info(
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_texture_info.py", line 23, in gather_texture_info
    return __gather_texture_info_helper(primary_socket, blender_shader_sockets, 'DEFAULT', export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 38, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_texture_info.py", line 46, in __gather_texture_info_helper
    'index': __gather_index(blender_shader_sockets, export_settings),
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_texture_info.py", line 129, in __gather_index
    return glt
```

Interestingly enough, this crash report cuts off the traceback. I investigated the file it crashed and this is line 129 as mentioned above:
[image]

So as far as I know this doesn't even seem to be the full traceback which is odd.

**System Specs:**

- GPU: RTX 3080 ti + GeForce GTX 1660
- RAM: 4x16GB = 64Gb
- CPU: Intel Core i7-7700 3.60GHz

I've ran multiple tests with this setup and crashes every time. As the software is running the system memory slowly creeps up to 100% in Task Manager, then Blender crashes. I've used GPU + CPU compute, only GPU compute using only my 3080 ti, but nothing seems to change.

My team and I believe the textures are the source of the issue, but we aren't sure. The reason we suspect the textures is because the external texture folder is about 11.5GB.

**My Question:**

Blender is obviously retaining unneeded files/information in memory when exporting this many files (most likely texture/material files). Why doesn't it just delete whatever files it is storing so that it doesn't pass my system memory limit? Is there anything I can do with the Blender Python API to stop this from happening? Maybe by deleting files from RAM after the models have been generated?

I also noticed this in Edit > System > Memory & Limits:

[image]

Is there a setting here^ I can possibly utilize to resolve my issue?

Thank you for reading this post and for your answers. I really appreciate you taking the time looking this over and helping me find the answer. Please let me know in a comment if there are any more details you would like me to provide.

**Edit:**
With further testing I have found that this issue only applies to exporting .gltf and .glb files. .fbx files export perfectly, do not increase memory over time, and do not result in a crash due to VRAM/RAM overflow. This seems like a very serious issue if and possibly a bug in Blenders GLTF/GLB file exporter. Am I wrong to assume this? I'm going to make a post on the devtalk.blender.org site about this.

**Traceback from the .crash.txt file when exporting .glb files:**

```
RuntimeError: Error: Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\__init__.py", line 628, in execute
    return gltf2_blender_export.save(context, export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_export.py", line 35, in save
    json, buffer = __export(export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_export.py", line 52, in __export
    __gather_gltf(exporter, export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_export.py", line 66, in __gather_gltf
    active_scene_idx, scenes, animations = gltf2_blender_gather.gather_gltf2(export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather.py", line 30, in gather_gltf2
    scenes.append(__gather_scene(blender_scene, export_settings))
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 38, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather.py", line 67, in __gather_scene
    node = gltf2_blender_gather_nodes.gather_node(
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_nodes.py", line 31, in gather_node
    children=__gather_children(vnode, blender_object, export_settings),
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_nodes.py", line 109, in __gather_children
    child_node = gather_node(vtree.nodes[child], export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_nodes.py", line 31, in gather_node
    children=__gather_children(vnode, blender_object, export_settings),
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_nodes.py", line 73, in __gather_children
    node = gather_node(c, export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_nodes.py", line 31, in gather_node
    children=__gather_children(vnode, blender_object, export_settings),
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_nodes.py", line 73, in __gather_children
    node = gather_node(c, export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_nodes.py", line 35, in gather_node
    mesh=__gather_mesh(vnode, blender_object, export_settings),
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_nodes.py", line 246, in __gather_mesh
    result = gltf2_blender_gather_mesh.gather_mesh(blender_mesh,
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 38, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_mesh.py", line 61, in gather_mesh
    primitives=__gather_primitives(blender_mesh, uuid_for_skined_data, vertex_groups, modifiers, materials, export_settings),
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_mesh.py", line 147, in __gather_primitives
    return gltf2_blender_gather_primitives.gather_primitives(blender_mesh,
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 38, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_primitives.py", line 81, in gather_primitives
    material = gltf2_blender_gather_materials.gather_material(
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 38, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_materials.py", line 53, in gather_material
    pbr_metallic_roughness, uvmap_actives_pbr_metallic_roughness = __gather_pbr_metallic_roughness(blender_material, orm_texture, export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_materials.py", line 334, in __gather_pbr_metallic_roughness
    return gltf2_blender_gather_materials_pbr_metallic_roughness.gather_material_pbr_metallic_roughness(
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 38, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_materials_pbr_metallic_roughness.py", line 19, in gather_material_pbr_metallic_roughness
    metallic_roughness_texture, use_active_uvmap_metallic_roughness_texture = __gather_metallic_roughness_texture(blender_material, orm_texture, export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_materials_pbr_metallic_roughness.py", line 140, in __gather_metallic_roughness_texture
    return gltf2_blender_gather_texture_info.gather_texture_info(
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_texture_info.py", line 23, in gather_texture_info
    return __gather_texture_info_helper(primary_socket, blender_shader_sockets, 'DEFAULT', export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 38, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_texture_info.py", line 46, in __gather_texture_info_helper
    'index': __gather_index(blender_shader_sockets, export_settings),
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_texture_info.py", line 129, in __gather_index
    return gltf2_blender_gather_texture.gather_texture(blender_shader_sockets, export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 38, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_texture.py", line 36, in gather_texture
    source=__gather_source(blender_shader_sockets, export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_texture.py", line 80, in __gather_source
    return gltf2_blender_gather_image.gather_image(blender_shader_sockets, export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 38, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_image.py", line 43, in gather_image
    buffer_view = __gather_buffer_view(image_data, mime_type, name, export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 38, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_image.py", line 101, in __gather_buffer_view
    return gltf2_io_binary_data.BinaryData(data=image_data.encode(mime_type))
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_image.py", line 117, in encode
    return self.__encode_unhappy()
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_image.py", line 141, in __encode_unhappy
    out_buf = np.ones(width * height * 4, np.float32)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\python\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 204, in ones
    a = empty(shape, dtype, order)
numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 256. MiB for an array with shape (67108864,) and data type float32
Location: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py:115  # Error

# backtrace
Exception Record:

ExceptionCode         : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Exception Address     : 0x00007FF69DFC7690
Exception Module      : blender.exe
Exception Flags       : 0x00000000
Exception Parameters  : 0x2
    Parameters[0] : 0x0000000000000000
    Parameters[1] : 0x0000000000000000


Stack trace:
blender.exe         :0x00007FF69DFC7690  Symbols not available


Loaded Modules :

# Python backtrace
```

*I have no idea what these tracebacks mean btw

Comment: The glTF exporter uses a cache that stays in memory after exporting. I'm not exactly sure what's in it though, or if it's big enough to matter. I think you'll get better results by filing an issue at https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues.

Comment: (I can tell you one thing you can do to use less memory is to make sure your textures are already packed in the glTF compatible way, eg. for metallic/roughness/AO. Your traceback suggests the exporting is having to pack them which is costky.)

Comment: @scurest Thank you for the link, I'll check it out and file an issue there. Yeah that would make sense, cache is mentioned in the traceback so I assumed its something to do with that. The weird thing is that it doesn't do it for other formats like fbx or obj. It's definitely big enough in my case, I see my RAM usage go up by the GB every 10 seconds when the program is running. Thank you again for the suggestion. I think my approach would be to find a way to delete that cache after each export, but I don't know how to go about that.

Comment: If I pack the files into the Blender file, I simply can't load the file after that (its a 11.5 GB external data folder, we found the limit for a .blend file is around 3GB at most). I've tried, it just crashes on startup.

Comment: The cache system is used so pervasively that appearing in the traceback isn't really proof of anything. Not packing them into the .blend, I mean packing the RGBA channels correctly, eg. G is roughness or whatever. Compare the images the exporter creates to the images you have on disk and they're probably different right?

Comment: Also you might try adding `export_keep_originals=True` to the op call.

Comment: @scurest Ok cool thanks for the export_keep_originals tip, that's really handy. It shouldn't matter if they are packed correctly, the files will still be cached right? It still doesn't change the fact that it's caching files after the export process is finished. So I need to find a way to bypass that or wipe the cache so that Blender doesn't overload my systems memory. You have to forgive me for my lack of texture/material knowledge, I know more python than I do Blender.

Comment: I know for a fact the cache is retained after export, but like I said, I don't know exactly what's in the cache, so I don't know whether your problem is related to the cache or not. I was just speculating, maybe shouldn't have mentioned it.

Comment: @scurest Oh ok I see, my bad for miss understanding. Thank you for your insight, I appreciate it :) I'll look into the RGBA channel packing and talk with our teams 3D expert, then report back if I find anything. Thank you once again

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
for obj in bpy.data.collections[some_collection].all_objects:
    obj.select_set(True)
```

will add the next object to the selection set, so every time your script iterates it add the next object to the selection set, so every export will include the last set of objects and everything will get exported, effectively creating a larger and larger set of objects to be exported.

You need to deselect the object after each iteration and reselect the next object:

```
for obj in bpy.data.collections[some_collection].all_objects:
    obj.select_set(True)
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj

    bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf(
       filepath=f"{Save_Path_To_Model_File}.gltf",
       check_existing=True,
       export_format='GLTF_SEPARATE',
       use_selection=True)

    obj.select_set(False)
```

Maybe I'm over simplifying this, but from the code snippet you've give it looks like the simplest answer

Comment: Oh yeah, my script doesn't do that, however it removes materials from previous exports as well. I forgot to include that in the example code above. The previously selected models aren't included in the exported gltf files when I import them into a separate blender file, let me give this a shot and see if it works. I also noticed from earlier that the files don't increase in size over the course of exporting.

Comment: Tried this method out, still experiencing the same memory creep and eventual crash due to VRAM and RAM overflow.

Comment: Shame, was hoping "the simplest way" would be the answer here. XD
Another thought, perhaps it's a driver issue? Looks like you're running Windows? If you have access to a Linux system it might be worth trying that as Linux generally has much less issues with memory leaks, where as Windows can be prone to serious memory problems, it can sometimes not free up RAM after it's used. Just a random possibility...